# How do I add an app (specifily porerpoing) to the Kiosk user creation app menu

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-powerpoint, kiosk

I want to set PowerPoint as the windows kiosk user app. I do not want to use the kiosk mode in PowerPoint. PowerPoint is not on the kiosk user app menu.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Kiosk applications on Windows 8+ can only be UWP using the built-in Kiosk functionality, so if your using the built-in function, what you want isn’t possible

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the method in this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app. Set up a single app kiosk on Windows 10.